# Get Stock quote using GoogleFinance for date and time

Tags: google-finance, stockquotes

I know that we can get stock quote from google finance and there are various attributes and period variables but I couldn't find any syntax to fetch stock prices for a past date and time. for example if I want to understand variance or pattern of a particular stock prices on a given day for every 15 minutes, I should be able to fetch prices for that stock by passing date and time instead of just date.

Can anybody help?